# how to loop through local storage to get text for a text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, local-storage

```
$("#hour8 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour8"));
$("#hour9 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour9"));
$("#hour10 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour10"));
```

this is the current code that I have minus 8 more hours, how can I loop through this to clean it up?

Comment: [Java is not JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Comment: Get the `<textarea>`s into a collection, loop over that collection, check if there's a value in `localStorage` for the id of the current `<textarea>`

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to reduce the amount of duplicated code you could loop through each hour and programatically target the html element and get the data for that element from `localStorage`.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].forEach(hour => {
  $(`#hour${hour} .description`).val(localStorage.getItem(`hour${hour}`));
})
```